# How is a file transfer accomplished when using sockets in C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'm working on a client/server project which requires I write my own solution instead of using an already made solution. One of my requirements is that I need the server to run on Linux and the client to run on Windows. Another requirement is that I need my solution to support as many Windows Operating Systems as possible. These requirements lead me to developing in C#, targeting the .NET Framework 2.0, for both the client and server - the client will be built using Visual Studio while the server will be built using Mono.

Part of the solution I'm developing will require that I transfer both messages (not like a chat program, these will be more of operational instructions for the client and server applications themselves), as well as transferring files to and from the client and server.

Here's where I'm stuck - sockets. I'm trying to figure out how to transfer a file and why I'm banging my head against the wall trying to write my own protocol when I don't believe I need to. I'm using sockets and not a TCPClient, I've followed the examples on MSDN for creating an Async client and server, but completely stuck just trying to send a file.

I think the reason I'm stuck is because of my ignorance in socket development (on top of that, I'm not a developer - I'm just good at researching and learning on the fly). All of the examples I can find for transferring a file simply show a code example of how to do it. I'm not interested in more code examples, I need to understand what's happening behind the scenes. When I call the Socket.BeginReceive method, what is it expecting and how do I know that the client will send more? Do I need to break up the data being sent into chunks that will fit inside a TCP packet, or is .NET doing that for me? If .NET is breaking up the data, then what goes into the buffer I've defined for the socket? Does the buffer wait until the TCP packets have filled it up before handing it over to my code?

In short, I think what I need is for someone to explain how a socket file transfer is accomplished - not how to accomplish it.

Comment: Raw sockets: it is the application's responsibility to handle "message framing" and constructing/deconstructing such from higher layers. There is really nothing else to it, other than a socket can only get or send a (relatively small) chunk of data at once. (Using TCP still takes care of ordering concerns and access to such is fundamentally a chunked stream.)

Comment: Sorry, but I think you will need to use those code examples and implement them, because they show how data is transferred via sockets. And as far as I understand you, that is exactly what you're about to do. You don't need to care too much about tcp packet sizes, .net sockets take care of that, but you will have to tell the receiver that a file is coming, how big it is and maybe a name or something....so in the end: a protocol.

Comment: You need to develop a Application Level with a command set and a response on top of the TCP Transport Level.  One end of the connection will be the Client (master) and the other end (server).  When transferring file data you will need to send the filename along with the contents of the file.  Each message must have one of the following terminations (or combination) 1) Ascii : Known character like '\n' 2) Ascii or Binary : Add byte length to beginning of message 3) Ascii or Binary : Fixed length messages base on type of message.

Comment: @jdweng Byte length in the beginning is the best in my opinion (it's what I use by the way). I'd say it's the most failsafe way, since when using a termination character one cannot be sure that the byte-content of a file _doesn't_ contain the same character represented in byte form.

Comment: **@user2864740** - I need to frame each message into chunks manageable by my application, and let the .NET Framework worry about the network, right?

Comment: **@RenéVogt** - Whatever chunk size (buffer size) I decide to use in my application, the .NET Framework will take care of cutting that up further into TCP packets and ensuring delivery to the recipient. For instance, if I use a buffer size of 52428800 bytes (50MB), the .NET Framework will worry about splitting that into packets, sequence the packets, and send them to the recipient - is that correct?

Comment: **@jdweng** - Since the recipient can't know what exactly it is I'm sending, my application needs to, as @RenéVogt stated, have it's own protocol. And I must design this protocol such that messages are structured in a way that instructs the recipient of it's contents as well as deliver the actual content, correct?

Comment: In order for your app to know what it's sending and receiving you can append a 5 byte-long header to the beginning of every message/"packet" you send. The first 4 bytes (byte 0-3) will be the length of your message in bytes. The next byte (the fifth byte at index 4) is a one byte header telling the recipient what kind of message or packet this is. For example: if the fifth byte is 0, then it's a chat message, but if it's 1 then it's the name of the file you're about to send, etc. etc.

Comment: I've created a TCP based protocol for sending and receiving packets properly. The packets are automatically length-prefixed, see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34630764/3740093 - Although this is in VB.NET you could try using an online converter OR simply put the classes in a VB.NET project and compile them to a DLL-file (which then can be imported into C#).