# TCP/ip recive connection but locks up when trying to read data

Tags: vb.net, tcp

Please can someone tell me why my server locks up when my rclient connects and try to send data?

If I comment out:

```
Dim bytes(rclient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
            rstream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(rclient.ReceiveBufferSize))
            RString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
            TextBox2.Text = RStringcode here
```

and just have

```
TextBox2.Text = ("Remote connected")
```

the server picks up on a connected client so it must be something i have done with the .read ?

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO.Ports

Dim tclient As New TcpClient
Dim tstream As NetworkStream
Dim rclient As New TcpClient
Dim rstream As NetworkStream
Dim sArray() As String
Dim Tricopter As New TcpListener(2000)
Dim Remote As New TcpListener(2001)
Dim myVal As String
Dim TricopterThread As New Thread(AddressOf TricopterThreadSub)
Dim RemoteThread As New Thread(AddressOf RemoteThreadSub)
Dim tre(tclient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
Dim TState = False
Dim RState = False
Dim SerialSwitch = False
Dim Toggle = False
Dim TString As String
Dim RString As String
Dim Remo(rclient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
Dim TSendText() As Byte


Private Sub RemoteThreadSub()
    rclient = Remote.AcceptTcpClient
    rstream = rclient.GetStream
    RState = True
End Sub

Private Sub TricopterThreadSub()
    tclient = Tricopter.AcceptTcpClient
    tstream = tclient.GetStream
    TState = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    Tricopter.Start()
    Remote.Start()
    Timer1.Start()
    TricopterThread.Start()
    RemoteThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    myVal = ">" & TrackBar1.Value & "," & TrackBar2.Value & "," & TrackBar3.Value & "," & TrackBar4.Value & "/n"

    Try

        If TState = False Then

            TextBox1.Text = ("No tricopter connected")

        Else

            TextBox1.Text = myVal

            If Toggle = False Then
                TSendText = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myVal)
            End If


            If Toggle = True Then
                TSendText = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(RString)
            End If
            tstream.Write(TSendText, 0, TSendText.Length)
        End If




        If RState = False Then

            TextBox2.Text = ("No Remote connected")

        Else
            ' TextBox2.Text = ("Remote connected")
            Dim bytes(rclient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
            rstream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(rclient.ReceiveBufferSize))
            RString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
            TextBox2.Text = RString

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub


Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If Toggle = False Then
        CheckBox1.CheckState = 1
        Toggle = True
    Else
        CheckBox1.CheckState = 0
        Toggle = False
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What do you mean locks up? Please review your code and post only the relevant sections

Comment: @MattWilko His code isn't really long... And infact, he actually has posted the relevant part(s). He said the problem probably was due to `rstream.Read()`, and that's infact exactly what it is.

Comment: Note: `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` is a bad idea - you should design your application to correctly marshal between threads. There are a ton of examples on how to do this

Comment: I just rewrote my answer. It implements a fully working TCP message algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: For those of you who have downloaded/tested this already, I made a bugfix to the classes so you'll need to redownload the sources if you're going to use them again.**

If you want to perform proper data transfer you'll need to use a more reliable method than just simply reading random data. And as **usr** pointed out: the `TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize` property *does not* tell you how much data there is to receive, nor how much data there is sent to you. `ReceiveBufferSize` is just a variable indicating how many bytes you are expected to get each time you read incoming data. Read the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivebuffersize(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) about the subject for more info.

As for the data transfer, I've created two classes which will do length-prefixed data transfer for you. Just import them to your project and you'll be able to start using them immediatelly. Link: http://www.mydoomsite.com/sourcecodes/ExtendedTcpClient.zip

### Example usage

**Server side**

1. First declare a new variable for `ExtendedTcpClient`, and be sure to
   include `WithEvents` in the declaration.

   ```
   Dim WithEvents Client As ExtendedTcpClient
   ```
2. Then you just need to use a normal `TcpListener` to check for
   incoming connections. The `TcpListener.Pending()` method can be
   checked in for example a timer.

   When you are to accept a new `TcpClient`, first declare a new
   instance of the `ExtendedTcpClient`. The class requires to have a
   form as it's owner, in this application `Me` is the current form.
   Then, use the `ExtendedTcpClient.SetNewClient()` method with
   `Listener.AcceptTcpClient()` as it's argument to apply the
   `TcpClient` from the listener.

   ```
   If Listener.Pending() = True Then
       Client = New ExtendedTcpClient(Me)
       Client.SetNewClient(Listener.AcceptTcpClient())
   End If
   ```
3. After that you won't be needing the timer anymore, as the
   `ExtendedTcpClient` has it's own thread to check for data.

   Now you need to subscribe to the `PacketReceived` event of the
   client. Create a sub like so:

   ```
   Private Sub Client_PacketReceived(sender As Object, e As ExtendedTcpClient.PacketReceivedEventArgs) Handles Client.PacketReceived

   End Sub
   ```

   In there you can for example output the received packet as text into
   a `TextBox`. Just check if the packet header is `PlainText` and then
   you can convert the received packets contents (which is an array of
   bytes, accessed via `e.Packet.Contents`) to a string and put it in
   the `TextBox`.

   ```
   If e.Packet.Header = TcpMessagePacket.PacketHeader.PainText Then
       TextBox1.AppendText("Message recieved: " & System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Packet.Contents) & Environment.NewLine)
   End If
   ```
4. Lastly, when closing the form you just need to disconnect the client.

   ```
   Private Sub ServerWindow_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
       If Client IsNot Nothing Then Client.Disconnect()
   End Sub
   ```

And that's it for the server side.

---

**Client side**

1. For the client side you will only be needing a normal `TcpClient` (**unless** you don't want to receive data there too).

   ```
   Dim Client As New TcpClient
   ```
2. Then connect to the server via the IP and port you've given the listener.

   ```
   Client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 5555) 'Connects to localhost (your computer) at port 5555.
   ```
3. Now if you want to send plain text to the server you'd do something like this:

   ```
   Dim MessagePacket As New TcpMessagePacket(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(TextBox2.Text), TcpMessagePacket.PacketHeader.PainText)
   MessagePacket.Send(Client) 'Client is the regular TcpClient.
   ```

And now everything should be working!

Link to a complete example project: http://www.mydoomsite.com/sourcecodes/TCP%20Messaging%20System.zip

If you want to add more headers to the class, just open `TcpMessagePacket.vb` and add more values in the `PacketHeader` enum (located in the region called `Constants`).

Hope this helps!

---

### Screenshot from the example project

(Click the image for larger resolution)

[image: ExtendedTcpClient example project output]

Comment: And what if no data is available? What is he supposed to do then?

Comment: @usr Is that the reason for a downvote? He cannot do anything if there's no data sent to the stream other than making it block the rest of the code from executing! -Which is not what he wanted. `DataAvailable` will be True when there's at least one byte sent to the NetworkStream.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason for the downvote. What if one byte comes through, then DA==0, then another one comes? He will miss the second one and never resume reading. The way to go is to always have a read outstanding, for example on a background thread or using async IO.

Comment: DataAvailable *cannot* be used to detect the end of message.

Comment: @usr I didn't say it could. In order to properly detect the end of the message you'd have to use something like length-prefixed messages. But I gave a solution to his problem.

Comment: Since your code stops doing anything in case DA == 0, it will just hang randomly from time to time. This solves nothing. You *have* to have a reading loop going on. No other way to detect new incoming data.

Comment: It won't hang. He put the code in a timer, which means it will execute the DA block whenever there's data available. It still cannot do anything if there's no data to use. Doesn't matter if you use `NetworkStream` or `StreamReader` or whatever. No data, nothing to use/handle.

Comment: I'm going to modify my answer to create a complete, working message system so that the OP will not have to worry about getting partial messages. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that reads return a specific amount of data such as `ReceiveBufferSize`. That is not true. A read returns at least one byte, that is all.

Just to clarify, TCP does not support message based transfer.

The correct way to read depends on the protocol. If the exact number of bytes expected is known you need to read in a loop until so many bytes are received (or use BinaryReader which does that for you).

For a line based protocol you can use `StreamReader.ReadLine` which again automates the looping.

`ReceiveBufferSize` is completely unrelated to how much data is available or will come.

`DataAvailable` is how much data can be read right now without blocking. But more data might come. It is almost always a bug to use it. Might return 0 at any time even if data comes in 1ms later.

Comment: On `Socket` it is an integer. TcpClient.DataAvailable is just Socket.DataAvailable != 0. Anyway, does not matter. Unusable properties.

Comment: They're indeed not unusable. Infact they come in very handy for example length-prefixed messages.

Comment: For length prefixed messages you cannot use DataAvailable to tell how long the message is. So not sure how it would help.

Comment: I didn't say you could, still! But you use it to know if there's any data available. THEN IF THERE IS you can start reading. It stops one's code from being blocked completely.

Comment: I've rewritten my entire answer. Care to take a look? :)

Comment: @VisualVincent the client has a bug in that it does not use the return value of Read in two cases. It might happen that the incoming data is read one byte at a time.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean...? Are you saying the packets are split in two (or more)?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. It's possible that it doesn't read the entire "packet" if there's a slight delay when sending the entire thing. Am I right?

Comment: Think I fixed it, thanks for pointing it out :). If you'd like to check, just redownload the files (I overwrote the old ones at my server).