# how to send an image over a tcp stream- c# winForms

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp

I'm trying to send a picture over a TCP stream on my C# Winforms chat project. The problem is that when it arrives you can see only a blank photo.

- to send image, the program you need to click the button1 is in the server, and the client check if the server sent "hii" before... It's kind of dumb but please ignore.

This is my code:

**Client:**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace CLIENT
{
    public partial class client : Form
    {
        Socket sock;

        public client()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sock = socket();
            listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            listBox1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(listBox1_DrawItem);

        }
        Socket socket()
        {
            return new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        }
        private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            //
            // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
            // Create a new Brush and initialize to a Black colored brush
            // by default.
            //
            e.DrawBackground();
            Brush myBrush = Brushes.Black;
            //
            // Determine the color of the brush to draw each item based on 
            // the index of the item to draw.
            //
            switch ((String)listBox1.Items[e.Index])
            {
                case "other:":
                    myBrush = Brushes.Green;
                    break;
                case "you:":
                    myBrush = Brushes.Red;
                    break;


            }
            //
            // Draw the current item text based on the current 
            // Font and the custom brush settings.
            //
            e.Graphics.DrawString(((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(),
                e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
            //
            // If the ListBox has focus, draw a focus rectangle 
            // around the selected item.
            //
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();


        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
        public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
        {

           // Bitmap bmp;
           // using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
            //{
              //  bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
            //}
            //return bmp;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
            Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            return returnImage;
        }

        private void connectionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                sock.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox2.Text), 3));
                new Thread( () =>
                {
                    read();



                }).Start();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("CONNECTION FAILED");
            }
        }
        void read()
        {

            while(true)
            {
                 try
                    {
                        byte[] buffer =new Byte[255];
                        int rec = sock.Receive(buffer,0, buffer.Length, 0);
                        if (rec <= 0)
                        {
                            throw new SocketException();
                        }
                        Array.Resize(ref buffer, rec);

                        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                             {
                                 if (listBox1.Items.Count > 1)
                                 {
                                    if (listBox1.Items[listBox1.Items.Count - 1].Equals("hii"))
                                       {

                                         Image i=byteArrayToImage(buffer);
                                           pictureBox1.Image =i ;

                                       }
                                  }
                                 listBox1.Items.Add("other:");
                                listBox1.Items.Add(Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer));
                             });

                    }
               catch
                {
                        MessageBox.Show("DISCONNECTION!");
                        Application.Exit();
                }
           }  
        }


        private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("you:");
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
            byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
            sock.Send(data, 0, data.Length, 0);

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Server:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace server
{
    public partial class server : Form
    {
        Socket sock;
        Socket acc;


        public server()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            //this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
           listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
           listBox1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(listBox1_DrawItem);


        }
        Socket socket()
        {
            return new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        }
        public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
        public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
            Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            return returnImage;
        }

        private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("you:");
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
            byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
            acc.Send(data, 0, data.Length, 0);


        }
       private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
    //
    // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
    // Create a new Brush and initialize to a Black colored brush
    // by default.
    //
    e.DrawBackground();
    Brush myBrush = Brushes.Black;
    //
    // Determine the color of the brush to draw each item based on 
    // the index of the item to draw.
    //
    switch ((String)listBox1.Items[e.Index])
    {
        case "other:":
            myBrush = Brushes.Green;
            break;
        case "you:":
            myBrush = Brushes.Red;
            break;


    }
    //
    // Draw the current item text based on the current 
    // Font and the custom brush settings.
    //
    e.Graphics.DrawString(((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(), 
        e.Font, myBrush,e.Bounds,StringFormat.GenericDefault);
    //
    // If the ListBox has focus, draw a focus rectangle 
    // around the selected item.
    //
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();


    }
        private void listenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sock = socket();

            sock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(0, 3));
            sock.Listen(0);

            new Thread(() =>
                {
                    acc = sock.Accept();
                    MessageBox.Show("CONNECTED ACCEPTED!");
                    sock.Close();
                    while(true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            byte[] buffer =new byte[255];
                            int rec =acc.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0);

                            if (rec<=0)
                            {
                                throw new SocketException();
                            }

                            Array.Resize(ref buffer, rec);
                            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                            {                             

                                listBox1.Items.Add("other:");




                                listBox1.Items.Add(Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer));

                            });
                        }
                        catch{
                                MessageBox.Show("DISCONNECTION!");
                                Application.Exit();
                        }
                    }
                }).Start();

        }

        private void server_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //this.Size = new Size(0, 0);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


           byte[] data = imageToByteArray(Image.FromFile("c:\\ss\\gg.png"));
            acc.Send(data, 0, data.Length, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: please ignore the horrible english

Comment: As TCP is stream-based, you should focus on implementing length-prefixed data.

Comment: can u send a sample code?

Comment: It's in VB.NET, but you could try converting it or just compiling it to a DLL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34630764/3740093 - But you should do some research about the subject as it's a somewhat complex task.

Comment: I followed this article the first time I was going to perform this: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html