# Program Freezes when sending data via TCP/IP in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp

I have a program that is sending data to a server and it freezes when it tries to send the data.

```
  Dim postData = "000000001119001  MY0121     020216081825S0000000001233300000000002050"
                Dim client As New TcpClient(IPAddressTextbox.Text, 17476)

                ' Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
                Dim data As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData)

                ' Get a client stream for reading and writing.
                ' Stream stream = client.GetStream();
                Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()

                ' Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)

                Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", postData)

                ' Receive the TcpServer.response.
                ' Buffer to store the response bytes.

                data = New [Byte](256) {}

                ' String to store the response ASCII representation.
                Dim responseData As [String] = [String].Empty

                ' Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.  
                Dim bytes As Int32 = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)

                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)

                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData)
                ResponseBox.Text = responseData
                ' Close everything.
                stream.Close()
                client.Close()
```

I did some troubleshooting and found that it freezes on this line

```
Dim bytes As Int32 = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
```

I got this section of code from [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) because I am just getting into learning about TCP connections and figured Microsoft may be a good resource to learn from. I have verified that the server IP and Port are valid and do accept connections from me.

Comment: You could try my `ExtendedTcpClient` class. It handles both sending and receiving and ensures that no received data is partial. When you want to close it just call `.Disconnect()`. DO NOTE however that both the client _and_ the server **must** use this (or something that does the exact same thing) or else things will break. With that said, have a link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34630764/3740093

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> figured Microsoft may be a good resource to learn from

Hahaha... :( The MSDN socket code is one of the worst pieces of socket code to be found.

If the read "hangs" this means that the remote side did not send even a single byte. My guess: Your request is malformed or not complete. The other side is waiting for you to send complete data.

Be aware that reads can be partial. You usually need to loop until you have all the data you expect. Assume that each read will return only a single byte. Your code must be able to deal with that. You could try `new StreamReader(new NetworkStream(socket)).ReadToEnd()`.

---

This Microsoft sample code is just shameful:

```
// String to store the response ASCII representation.
String responseData = String.Empty;

// Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);
```

They do say that it's the "first batch" but that still leaves the code broken.

Comment: If the MSDN example is no good where would I get a good example for this?

Comment: I don't know, most internet socket code is hairraisingly broken. Maybe Stephen Cleary's blog has a series.

Comment: After looking more closely at what was being sent I noticed that not all of the expected data was passed to the server and so you were correct in saying 

"If the read "hangs" this means that the remote side did not send even a single byte. My guess: Your request is malformed or not complete. The other side is waiting for you to send complete data."